# Can distance be calculated to destination feature based on attribute in source?

Tags: distance, sql-server-spatial

Is it possible to specify which destination point to calculate distance to based on an attribute in the source?

STDistance will give me the distance each student (point) is to their closest school (point).

When I pull a list of students based on their boundary school number (the school they should go to based on their proximity to their house), I also get back their choice school number (the school they actually go to).

I would like to calculate the distance each student is from their choice school.

I'm using SQL Server 2012, hence the STDistance function (rather than ST_Distance in PostGIS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just need an `INNER JOIN` between students table and schools like

```
SELECT p.id
       ,stdistance(p.geom,s.geom) 
FROM pupils AS p 
  JOIN schools AS s 
    ON p.choice_id = s.id
```